# Configuring the emulator DNS settings

Tags: android, dns, android-emulator

I am struggling to get the Android emulator to use a custom DNS server, which is running on localhost (127.0.0.1).

As of now, I have tried various approaches trying to convince the emulator to use my DNS server, so far without success. In the end, it always boils down to the following error message:

`net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED`

I tried configuring the Emulator's DNS Settings from Emulator guide but still not luck
http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/emulator.html#dns

Comment: I'm not sure whether that's actually an answer which fits you but oh well; the app "DNS Changer" by Frostnerd is able to set your DNS server to the localhost (it's the only one of its kind which can do that - at least as far as I have seen). You'll have to join the beta program though, it's not in the production version. If you then still get the error your local DNS server might not be working, the app does its job for me.

Answer (score 1):

You may be able to give this guide a go, I use this for my dev setup and have modes to test local dns servers.

- Download (Daedalus) and open the application.
- Click on the menu then click “Servers”

[image: menu]

- Click the add button and add the two google servers “8.8.8.8” and “8.8.4.4”, You can substitute these for your preferred DNS provider as well.

[image: dns settings]

- Activate these dns servers in the menu by clicking on “Settings”
- Then select Google and Google 2 from the settings.

  Source: https://blog.silocitylabs.com/post/2018/03/02/changing-dns-settings-for-android-development/